# How to launch browser to open local file

Tags: android

I'm trying to send intent to browser to open local file. I wish to use default browser to open this file.

```
if(file.exists()){
  Log.d(TAG, "file.exists");
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));
  context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

But it throws me and exeption

```
08-10 13:27:58.993: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28453): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///sdcard/release_notes.htm }
```

If I use following intent browser opens google.com as expected

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
```

Also when I write the file url `(file:///sdcard/release_notes.htm)` to browser address bar it opens it as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add browsable category in the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to help  
`08-10 14:03:48.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29612): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=file:///sdcard/release_notes.htm } `

Comment: hmm, weird, I don't seem to have any problems with this on my phone :( - double check that your sdcard is not mounted to a computer when you try this.

Comment: maybe you could try adding the browser classname explicitly to the intent: `intent.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");`

Comment: I don't think it's accessibility issue because the browser opens it if I write the url manually to address bar. Also I think file.exists() should return false if it could not access the file. And shouldn't it throw a different exception...? Could there be different behavior between devices? I'm running desire hd

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between devices, it should just work. I'm currently unable to test it on a desire hd, might get my hands on one tomorrow...

Comment: adding that class name did the trick. It works now! Thank you for your efford!

Comment: This is very strange because adding the category is exactly what the documentation says to do. I don't think adding the explicit class name is a good solution, because the user might have set Opera / Firefox / Other as their favorite browser. There is no reason to run the Android browser in that case.

Comment: Not work for me. the solution was: intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/html");

Answer (score 10):

The browser is started only for HTML and other compatible files. this should work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/html");
```

Answer (score 6):

This is what's working for me. I took the mime type directly from the [Manifest.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) of the Android's default browser. Apparently the text/html mime is only for http(s) and inline schemes.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(filePath), "application/x-webarchive-xml");
startActivity(intent);
```

Not sure if it works in every android/phone/browser combination but it's the only way I could get it to work.

Edit: Tested with chrome and doesn't work. Also doesn't work with my 2.3.3 device. Seems to work with the default browser in Android 4.0.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slighly more robust approach:

```
private void openInBrowser(File file) {
    final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    try {
        final Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        browserIntent.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
        browserIntent.setData(uri);
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        final Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        browserIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/html");
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
}
```

I've tested this on a Nexus One (API 16, 4.1.2), where the `try` works, and a Nexus 5 (API 22, 5.1.1), where only the `catch` works.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this works:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/html");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the new activity has no access to the html page inside your app since it is a different app and it has no permissions to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This code works on both API 10 and API 11.

```
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/index.html");

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), "application/x-webarchive-xml");
// Have to add this one in order to work on Target 2.3.3 (API 10)
intent.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```