# How to open downloaded file in Android programatically?

Tags: java, android, file

Using this code i am able to download file from URL in Android and saving it into SDCard, is there any way to open this file programatically ?

Can Intent help in this ?

```
private static class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    static String DownloadUrl = "http://00.00.00.00/abc.crt";
    static String fileName = "def.crt";
```

Async Task to download

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    DownloadFromUrl();
    return null;
}


public static void DownloadFromUrl() {

   try {
           File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();               

           File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/SDCard");
           if(dir.exists()==false) {
                dir.mkdirs();
           }

           URL url = new URL(DownloadUrl); //you can write here any link
           File file = new File(dir, fileName);

           long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
           Log.d("DownloadManager", "download begining");
           Log.d("DownloadManager", "download url:" + url);
           Log.d("DownloadManager", "downloaded file name:" + fileName);

           /* Open a connection to that URL. */
           URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

           /*
            * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
            */
           InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
           BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

           /*
            * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
            */
           ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
           int current = 0;
           while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
              baf.append((byte) current);
           }

           /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
           fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
           fos.flush();
           fos.close();
           Log.d("DownloadManager", "download ready in" + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");




   } catch (IOException e) {
       Log.d("DownloadManager", "Error: " + e);
   }

}


}
```

Comment: how do you want to open it? As text or binary or with an application?

Comment: Yes, `Intents` are the way to go; see Google or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009452/how-to-launch-browser-to-open-local-file).

Comment: When you say 'open', what do you mean? What's the filetype (as in what's .crt)? What's the data? String? Audio?

Answer (score 0):

Use a FileInputStream and load the downloaded file to memory
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html

If the file is of a specific extension there might be other ways of loading it that doesn't involve resolving it to a byte array

Comment: Thanks Udrian & Matt, Ideally .CRT is VPN Certificate file, which when installed popups up notification to enter Certificate Name and then Installs file for Android VPN app. I guess if we want to read a file then we require FileInputStream, to open this file should not intents be used ?

Comment: GJordis it will be opened as binary file which would invoke VPN App when opened

Comment: I somehow missed that it was a .CRT file. And yes, if your intention is to prompt user to open this file outside of your application then you should use a Intent. This might help you a bit http://indyvision.net/2010/03/android-using-intents-open-files/

Comment: Thanks Udrian, I tried the same thing, but as i am using Async Task it won't allow me to invoke intent there.

    `File videoFile2Play = new File("/sdcard/nice_movie.mpeg");
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(videoFile2Play), "video/mpeg");
    startActivity(i);`

Comment: Have you tried invoking it on the main thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388415/call-main-thread-from-secondry-thread-in-java-android

Comment: Udrian can u share an example as a reference to code i post above !!

Comment: activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        File file = new File(fileDir);
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_RUN);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimeType);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});

I don't really know how to specify the intent in order to open a crt file.

Comment: I guess this could be one of the way to do, but not sure where to post in above code, as Async Task will not accept intent 

      if(file.exists()){
               Log.d("DownloadManager", "file.exists");
               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));
               context.startActivity(intent);
             }