# Open html file in browser from intent

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types, android-browser

I would like to open downloaded html-files via browser by passing them into an intent and starting them out of my activity.

I know that there are dozen of threads about this problem (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009452/how-to-launch-browser-to-open-local-file)).

However, none of these approaches seem to work.

So far I have:

```
File file = //myHTMLFile;
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
browserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
browserIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
```

I tried setting **Mimeypes** like **text/html**, adding/removing categories and even using multipe mimetypes and the extra mimetype flag but none of these ideas worked for me.

Currently a "default" browser will open which cannot show the file. I would like to open files in Chrome, Firefox or other popular browsers.

Also weird: The Uri-String, which I receive from Uri.fromFile() is not openable by Chrome.

The path looks like **file:///data/data/myapp/website.html**.

The file itself is located at **/storage/emulated/0/myapp/website.html**. Passing this value with file:/// as prefix, Chrome will show the website.

**Is Uri.fromFile correct?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The path looks like file:///data/data/myapp/website.html.

Assuming that `myapp` is really your application ID, this is pointing at internal storage, and no other app can access that (exception: rooted devices).

> Is Uri.fromFile correct?

`Uri.fromFile()` works fine, but your `file` that you are passing in is not being created correctly.

Beyond that, please bear in mind that browsers do not have to support the `file://` scheme, and so some may not.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I'm creating the file in external storage now. Are there any other ways to open a file in Chrome directly via intent? When copying the file:///-path in Chrome directly, it will load the website

Comment: @Frame91: "I'm creating the file in external storage now" -- that is not what `file` is pointing to, based upon what you have in your question. "Are there any other ways to open a file in Chrome directly via intent?" -- I do not know what schemes Chrome supports, and those schemes could change in future versions of Chrome. `http` and `https` seem like strong candidates, and it would be nice if Chrome supported `content`, for use with `FileProvider` or your own `ContentProvider`.

Comment: I fixed the external-storage issue now, that's what I meant. I had a minor error and now the URI is created correctly. Thanks for pointing out the mistake!

Comment: well... after further investigation... most of the browsers do not accept file:// schemes..which is a pitty as I wanted to implement an offline-rss-reader (prefetching) but still using external browsers

Comment: As I couldn't find any way to solve my problem, I will accept your answer. There is no way to support the file// at the moment... A bit sad in my opinion